# How to write data to a text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a sport prediction game for my Grade 11 year and I'm having issues writing data to a text file. I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1. I'm using a button where every time it is pressed data entered by the user must be written to the text file. The text file is empty in the beginning and I need to add data to it. After the first click on the button the data keep rewriting itself and the new data is not added. It needs to be in a new line each time. Thank you very much. Some coding would be awesome!

Comment: I agree.  Some coding would by awesome... from you.  Please share what you have so far with the Stack Overflow community, and we will see how we can help you.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: You learn by doing, not having other do it for you.

Comment: Also, do you have any code you wrote?

Comment: Write and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick search for appending to a file (usually a good thing to do): [this question seems to be what your looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java).

Comment: warning off topic: congrats on 3k rep :)

Comment: Not sure its really off topic, the question was about appending to a file, which is what I responded to. I normally write much more detailed responses, but there was no code in the question and I was guessing the person asking the question just didnt know where to really start. (Im also hesitant to give away a lot of code for homework where the person hasnt really shown any of their own work)

Comment: Oh sorry, you misunderstood. I meant that my comment was off topic.

Comment: nice, yeah sorry thanks.

Comment: The code I have so far is :                              Sting fileName ="resources/Scores.txt";                              try                                                                                               {                                                                                                        PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName,true));

Comment: Does this work when you have an empty textfile as well?

Comment: I think so, but its been a long time. try it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
private boolean appendToFile(String fileName, String data, String lineSeparator) 
        throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    File file = new File(fileName)

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        writer.append(data);
        writer.append(lineSeparator);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```